# The compression mode specified in GZip header is unknown in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I am trying to Unzip my string but i am getting an error.
**int rByte = sr.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);**
Getting an error in this line. can you please tell me where am i doing wrong.

```
 public static string UnZip(string value, int Contentlength)
    {
        try
        {

        //Transform string into byte[]
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[value.Length];
        int indexBA = 0;
        foreach (char item in value.ToCharArray())
        {
            byteArray[indexBA++] = (byte)item;
        }

        //Prepare for decompress
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
        System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sr = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
            System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);

        //Reset variable to collect uncompressed result
        byteArray = new byte[Contentlength];

        //Decompress
        int rByte = sr.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        //Transform byte[] unzip data to string
        System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(rByte);
        //Read the number of bytes GZipStream red and do not a for each bytes in
        //resultByteArray;
        for (int i = 0; i < rByte; i++)
        {
            sB.Append((char)byteArray[i]);
        }
        sr.Close();
        ms.Close();
        sr.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return sB.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

  public static string Zip(string value)
    {
        //Transform string into byte[]
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[value.Length];
        int indexBA = 0;
        foreach (char item in value.ToCharArray())
        {
            byteArray[indexBA++] = (byte)item;
        }

        //Prepare for compress
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sw = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
            System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);

        //Compress
        sw.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        //Close, DO NOT FLUSH cause bytes will go missing...
        sw.Close();

        //Transform byte[] zip data to string
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(byteArray.Length);
        foreach (byte item in byteArray)
        {
            sB.Append((char)item);
        }
        ms.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return sB.ToString();
    }
```

i am sending the value through the url like this

\b\0\0\0\0\0\0íYMoâ:ý+(o1P%!Î°£|´ Eö-Ybß;r¡¼yýïïÚqBHÔJÝ Á¢(ççÞë{|R?V8°ºíïð±­{´ÅV×zbH£VÈÖüà]k¥$,N-Û#øêZ_Ûm7pÜ«éóÕ3¢ný×*¾û@ð\bnÐi\"xßDèT\bAÁÿõö¤dI¬ª6õßã]~q\bÄ\aX\"BÿÇ5Ãàt¾OðÂê:vÌä#nªhö]eIÐÄD\"j®aø\b¦3\0YF)àw$Â½²F4Å\0\rHP´q±Eð5ZXê¸pÇs×k5Cn^1ÀéJDæëDMybD¦:8Àq«¯±)I%\aÒÑeÆ1ÙUOà8W\nó]åÀrY%úÁ¯\rz¯ú£U~ç:¨D*+\/ô(Û£\f¦¨.0øWK`ÁªáÖy ©<rª·CômyìtÕøÉNö\\\t7t~9è{ÌWHé\rÀpbBÍ·èH\v\vºË$2çA)Î(\v\bÚF4¥Ï)ûk¤?5­\n=Hò)ÅbÈ²-º0-°Üàpmø®H!Esú¬×X\tR·Â±Èo^91ÐÔI%ûC£*÷ßDnJr]þ}è²F!ú°ü\a¯äÉMãiyµÏÊ#¼á½×#¼G\\<â³=ÂÑsð\bïcá£GtNxDç½Ñ¹xÄÅ#>ÿÿsñÎÇ<¢sáð\bÿ½á_<ââï½à<<ÂÿGøçèÁ\t\bÞëÁÅ#.ñÙá/çw|Ì#òÓòúÓ²­DBÎ~ë9îuÛùÚv½¹ëw=¯ë8À²¨1¸yZzÄ`ä7V¼ÔôjLbñQ]h\bÆXbjj\%0q¡HC_t}Õûß ôDdQIJ°\0I*Õ¼¥ì;YkJHÔì¸PPÍ6&«áÕT:S-^ËÑC¸ðH£b«Hº#¨¶P~õÜKAÙÚË$J\"0åb×Lr¥³{\aE¹Bù®ïêË=¾EYlvÜ5WðX`RKÚÌ)_Óß(¹T¦'PÂÕsbêp9ç÷Ò9ZR\\ö5ãB.÷%gÙvÄ¾ÄÔ3d ñV£V\0G8¤Çô:Æ1fQ-D«_8ºAâ_Ã3±e=¦¼pªw2góQD\fc¨#L'eawöG·\nYÃv!¹ÌÔv/c¢­üÉEÛÜHY\r½x£0!ã)<×ytP»z+H4~³©z¿)üE]p¦ÄU½ÊØ¥XðEÚ)Áv\"±úûTÏ¡,)!2âLycÐùW©Î³­|\\oYFzæêÇöí¯öµýÍþn»Ñç,\"*\n¾.õõ`­X¹±\0\0

Comment: Transforming a string to a char array and then turning it in a byte array is dubious at best. Where does the string `value` come from, and how does it encode the binary data?

Comment: i am sending the value through the URL

Comment: i am edited my code please have a look